# How to disable introspection on graphene-python?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

The [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/queryvalidation/#disable-introspection) give this explanation:

```
validation_errors = validate(
    schema=schema.graphql_schema,
    document_ast=parse('THE QUERY'),
    rules=(
        DisableIntrospection,
    )
```

... but leave a "THE QUERY" placeholder for the `document_ast` parameter.

What should be used so that introspection is disabled for all queries?